# how to make next plot in r into shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinyapps

in r, we have [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dIz0.png) to see next plot, but how about shiny? I have 3 plot, that synchronize each other.

Comment: What is an m3 plot?

Comment: sorry I mean 3 plot, I use package stablespec